# When accumulatively recursing through user input, how to use value of local variable which is set at the last call?

Tags: c

I have a problem in C where I'm supposed to recursively read user input (integers), and print them back in the reverse order with the total number of integers that were read added to every number.

E.g. if I were to enter 1,1,2,1 the output should be 4,5,4,4

I have the recursion+reverse printing part done but the value of `i` in my code that is being added to each number is from the local scope. How do I do it such that it uses the last value of `i` without using `static` or global ints?

```c
    void reverse_and_add(int i) {
      int n = read_int();
      if (n != ERR_READ) {
        i++;
        reverse_and_add(i);
        printf("%d\n", n + i);
      }
    }
```

Edit: I know this can be solved using `static int i`, but this problem is not supposed to use `static` ints

Comment: Pass another parameter?

Comment: what do you mean? `i` currently is where im keeping track of count. whatever paramter is passed, the `printf` statement will use it within its current scope

Comment: If you need to know `n` in the last call, then you can pass it as an additional parameter, e.g. `void reverse_and_add(int i, int lastn)`. You know the sum `n + i` but to know what either `n` or `i` was, you need to pass one or the other.

Comment: even with that, i dont think it'd help since the user can enter an indefinite amount of ints, `i` would still be within the local scope when finally we come around to printing. that being said, jwodder's answer below works and i cant believe i couldnt think of that

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but with `reverse_and_add(int i, int lastn)` where `i` is your `lastsum`, if you know `lastn`, then `lasti = lastsum - lastn`? (just pass `0` as the `lastn` on the first call)

Comment: i think the confusion is arising from what `i` is. It would probably be better named as `num_inputs` or something. With your suggestion, I would be able to print out `n` with the `num_inputs` or `i` upto the next read, but it wont stay consistent. What i needed was that for example after 5 inputs the user enters `"c"` which will cause a fail, the program should print out the ints in reverse order as they were read all with the same `num_inputs` added to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `reverse_and_add()` return the value of `i` after the processing is done:

```
int reverse_and_add(int i) {
  int n = read_int();
  if (n != ERR_READ) {
    i = reverse_and_add(i+1);
    printf("%d\n", n + i);
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Aah i was so close. I tried the returning thing, but I didnt set i equal to that, instead was trying `printf("%d\n", n + reverse_and_add(i))` if i had changed it to `i+1` instead it wouldve worked